# Nullable boolean field in xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

How would I make a field that allows the value of `true`, `false`, or `(NULL)`? What I'm currently doing is:

```
<xs:element name="IsPromotional" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="(true|false)?" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Instead of doing:

```
<xsd:element name="IsPromotional" type="xsd:boolean" minOccers="0" />
```

Because `IsPromotional` also accepts an empty value. How would I make a custom `xsd` field to allow true, false, or '' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that when you write `(NULL)`, you mean the empty string?

It depends a bit what you are using the schema for. If it is only for validation, then there's no meaningful difference between a string field that allows "true" and "false" and a boolean field that allows "true" and "false", in which case a string field with enumerated values ("true", "false", "") works just fine. But if it's also for data typing (e.g. JAXB, or schema-aware XSLT/XQuery) then it's better to make this a boolean.

My preferred approach is to define a type that's a list of booleans with minLength 0, maxLength 1.

(This also allows 0 and 1, which you can prevent by subtyping xs:boolean)

Comment: thanks for the response and I like your "0"/"1" approach. Would you mind posting the xsd code to define that special type and I'll accept your answer?

Comment: No, I'll leave you to do that. Generally I prefer to point people in the right direction rather than holding their hand and taking them to the destination: they'll learn more that way.